# Discord.js select menu interaction fails response after selecting option

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a select menu where once a menu item is selected, it should send an embed with some info but it doesn't, only "This interaction failed" is displayed. There is no error in the console.

**Here is my code:**

```
`const {SlashCommandBuilder, ActionRowBuilder , StringSelectMenuBuilder, EmbedBuilder,} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test')
    .setDescription('ทดสอบ'),
async execute  (interaction)  {
    const menu = new ActionRowBuilder()
    .addComponents(
        new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId('select')
        .setPlaceholder('noting select game')
        .addOptions(
                {
                    label: 'BF',
                    description: "Test",
                    value: "OPT 1"
                },
                {
                    label: 'City Thailand',
                    description: "Test",
                    value: "OPT 2"
                },
            ),
        );

    await interaction.reply({ content: "you select", components: [menu]})
}
}`
```

If you look at the image below, you will see that it doesn't give me anything after I select an option. I use discord.js v14.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP4Ub.png)

Comment: _"it should send an embed with some info but it doesn't"_ Where is this part of code?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you code I can't quite tell what is wrong but I think it may have something to do you how you listen for the interaction. You probably want to  listen using a [`InteractionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/InteractionCollector)